# create Content Types like Excel,PowerPoint,One Note documents for document library in SP2013?

Tags: content-type, excel, powerpoint

I want to create Content Types like Excel,PowerPoint,One Note documents for document library in SP2013,by default once enable the content type in Advance settings,we can able to see the Word content type,In site settings->site content types i can able to create new content types,but by default word content type is coming,how to change to Excel,PowerPoint,One Note documents.

Answer (score 1):

There are no out of the box content types like Excel,PowerPoint,One Note in SharePoint 2013. You need to create your custom content types and add it your document library.

Comment: Yes i know we have to create custom content types,but i have to give the path for Excel,PowerPoint,One Note.default word having path like "Forms/template.dotx".Can any one suggest me how to give path for custom and the location path.

Comment: In the content type's Adavanced settings, Document Template section, don't use the "Enter the URL of an existing document template" option.  Instead, use the "Upload a new document template" option.  Save a blank file - Word, Excel, etc. - to your computer and upload as the template.  I've done this countless times over the years with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-multiple-Office-templates-to-a-document-library-cde94e90-a1ba-4b94-a187-600ed68562bb

Created custom content types and follow the above article to add the powerpoint, excel and onenote in the appropriate content type section

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, however there are a couple of points (assuming I'm understanding it a little).

Firstly, if you are looking to be able to show the OOTB meta that is shown in the excel docs etc.... then just create the meta data columns in the Content Type (you need to make sure it's named exactly the same, and is also the right type.) I've done this before and it pulls all of the properties in without any issue.

Secondly, and I doubt this is what you were asking, but in relation to the default Content Type, in the List Settings:
1. Turn on Content Types in Advanced Settings
2. Add multiple CT's (add from existing content types) 
3. Then reorder the content types

Thirdly, in the list view, make sure you are clicking the drop down arrow under the New Item button or you won't get the list of alternative content types.

Answer (score 0):

I may not provide the answer you are looking for, but why would you want to create a content type for different types of MS  Office files? Content types are designed for different types of content, where each type will get its own metadata (columns). Word document could be a number of different content types (invoice, proposal, agenda) and each will get their own metadata.

So if you are after creating unique content types, I suggest looking at different types of content and creating content types for those. And if you need to sort and filter by MS Office files, you can do so with an existing (file) type column that is available out of the box in SH2013